# DAX - Creating Categories Based on Order of Test Completion

Tags: dax, powerpivot

I have what may be kind of a complex issue.

I’m currently working with a data set in power query and wondering whether there was any way (within either power query, if not perhaps with a DAX formula) to create a flag that will place students in one of three categories based on the order in which they completed a test. I would have to take into consideration the date as well as time (so if a student completed an array of tests on the same date, the time would determine into which category they fell)

I have attached a sample workbook with anonymized data as well as the desired result which will (hopefully) be a clearer reference.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

[Working Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADQVw.png)

[Desired Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQ7jc.png)

Comment: Please post your example data as text rather than images.

Comment: Also, how are you grouping the six categories into the three you requested?